# Java 8 streams - map element to pair of elements

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, stream, java-stream

I have a stream of elements. I want to map each element to two different elements of the same type so that my stream will be two times longer in consequence.
I did this by concatenating two streams, but I'm wondering is it possible to do this simpler?
What I've done so far:

```
private List<String> getTranslationFilesNames() {
return Stream.concat(SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.stream()
                .map(lang -> PATH_TO_FILES_WITH_TRANSLATIONS_1 + lang + FILE_EXTENSION),
        SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.stream()
                .map(lang -> PATH_TO_FILES_WITH_TRANSLATIONS_2 + lang + FILE_EXTENSION))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I don't find this solution very elegant. Is there better approach to achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't care about the order, you can map each element to a pair of elements with `flatMap`:

```
private List<String> getTranslationFilesNames() {
    return SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.stream()
            .flatMap(lang -> Stream.of(PATH_TO_FILES_WITH_TRANSLATIONS_1 + lang + FILE_EXTENSION,
                                       PATH_TO_FILES_WITH_TRANSLATIONS_2 + lang + FILE_EXTENSION)),
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of creating a combined `Stream`, you can simply use the `#flatMap` operator to duplicate the input elements (note that this may be a suitable solution only if the elements order does not matter):

```java
private List<String> getTranslationFilesNames() {
  return SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.stream()
      .flatMap(s -> Stream.of(
              PATH_TO_FILES_WITH_TRANSLATIONS_1 + s + FILE_EXTENSION,
              PATH_TO_FILES_WITH_TRANSLATIONS_2 + s + FILE_EXTENSION
          )
      )
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: where is PATH_TO_FILES_WITH_TRANSLATIONS_1 ?

Comment: My bad, I've updated the answer to match your question.